# Incorrect Package Name in AndroidManifestFile when using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, package, android-manifest

I just created a new project in Android Studio.

However the package name in AndroidManifest.xml is incorrect.

Current I have : package="*UserName.appName*"

When it should be something like : package = *com.example.appName* ?

When I try to run the app, I get an error of "Manifest_Malformed"

So my idea is to change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml, however AndroidStudio will give me an error saying that it "cannot resolve the symbol MyActivity.

Is there something I must do with the gradle file? Thanks in advance for any help

```
EDIT : AndroidManifest.xml is added 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Rohan.unibargainr" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very inefficient solution to this problem....

I just created a new project and on the first page is an option to change the package name.

By default it is set to UserName.appName, so I just changed it to com.example.appName.

Not the best solution because I have to start from scratch now.